# Unable to extend javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, extend

I am just playing around with the idea of subclassing with Javascript. I like to pretend that extending native objects (like Array, String etc) is a bad idea. This, however true, is completely out of my understanding as to why.

Having said that, let's get on with it.

What I'm trying to do is to extend Array (now, `extend` may not be right term for what I'm doing)

I want to create my new class `MyArray` and I want to have 2 methods on it. `.add` and `.addMultiple`.

So I implemented it like this.

```
function MyArray(){
    var arr = Object.create(Array.prototype);
    return Array.apply(arr, arguments);
}

MyArray.prototype = Array.prototype;

MyArray.prototype.add = function(i){
    this.push(i);
}

MyArray.prototype.addMultiple = function(a){
    if(Array.isArray(a)){
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            this.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This works correctly, but if I do

```
console.log(Array.prototype.addMultiple );
console.log(Array.prototype.add);
```

I get `[Function]` and `[Function]`.
So this means my code is modifying the native `Array` object. Something that I am trying to avoid. How do I change this code in a way that those two `console.log`s will give me `undefined` but I am still able to use native `Array.prototype` methods like `.push`?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You should setup proper prototypes chain:

```
function MyArray(){
    Array.apply(this, arguments);
}

MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
```

[Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) just creates new object with specified prototype, so after this operation following is true:

```
MyArray.prototype !== Array.prototype; // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(MyArray.prototype) === Array.prototype; // true
```

Comment: Would it also be correct to say the current contents of `function MyArray` (the constructor) aren't really necessary?

Comment: Nope, doing this won't allow me to do `MyArray.prototype.add`. The `.add` will be undefined.

Comment: @Katana314: No! The `var arr = Object.create(Array.prototype);` in the constructor is just an explicit way of saying `var arr = []`;

Comment: Using `Object,create(Array.prototype);` gives me `TypeError: collection.add is not a function`

Comment: Also it will evaluate `console.log(collection instanceof MyArray);` to `false`.

Comment: Yep, I missed that constructor was also broken, I've already edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This:

MyArray.prototype = Array.prototype;

results in MyArray.prototype pointing to the same object as Array.prototype. So everything you do to MyArray.prototype after that will also be done to Array.prototype.

A way to solve this is to instead store a shallow copy of Array's prototype in MyArray:

MyArray.prototype = clone(Array.prototype);

I copied that from here:

[Copy prototype for inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488540/copy-prototype-for-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

use class [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  add(i) {
    this.push(i);
    return this;
  }
  addMultiple(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        this.add(a[i]);
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
}

var test = new MyArray();
test.addMultiple([1,2,3,4,5]).add(6).add(7);
console.log(test, test.indexOf(6));
```

Comment: Thank, I want to do it using ES5!

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.create(Array.prototype);
```

This just creates a new object and return the objects.

So as per your scenarios, you have just created array object and added some methods to your array object - MyArray. It will affect the native Array.

You're just modifying your cloned object.